# Replace a named comment using BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have the following:

```
<!--NAMED COMMENT<trans-unit id="1" reformat="yes">
<source>foo</source>
<target>bar</target>
</trans-unit>-->
```

I'd like to return

```
<trans-unit id="1" reformat="yes">
<source>foo</source>
<target>bar</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I cannot seem to strip the comments in questions. I can access those comments:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xlf, "lxml")
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
for comment in comments:
    print(comment)
```

but cannot return the souped object with those changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, do you want to remove the `NAMED COMMENT` part from the string that your code is printing?

Answer (score 1):

Your code prints this as the output:

```
NAMED COMMENT<trans-unit id="1" reformat="yes">
<source>foo</source>
<target>bar</target>
</trans-unit>
```

If you want to remove the `NAMED COMMENT` part from the string, you can simply use `strip('NAMED COMMENT')`. Something like this:

```
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.strip('NAMED COMMENT'))
```

Output:

```
<trans-unit id="1" reformat="yes">
<source>foo</source>
<target>bar</target>
</trans-unit>
```

If you want to save these changes in the list itself, you can use list comprehension.

```
comments = [x.strip('NAMED COMMENT') for x in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))]
```